# Eager loading nested relationships on the Auth::user() facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to eager load some relationships from my user model. The scenario is as follows: A user can have many `sales` and each sale can consist of many `items`.

I have setup the following relationships in my models:

**User Model:**

```
// Attach User Sales
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Sale::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Sale Model:**

```
// Attach Items
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'sale_id', 'id');
}
```

---

I can access the user sales by doing the following:

```
Auth::user()->sales
```

And i can then loop through these sales to get the corresponding items in the sale, like so:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->sales as $sale)
    {{ dump($sale) }}
    {{ dump($sale->items) }}
@endforeach
```

However, this then presents me with the `N+1` problem.

I was hoping to eager load the nested `items` relationship to reduce the query size.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Auth::user()->sales->with('items')->get()` How does that work? (if this doesn't work try `sales()` instead of `sales` in the previous query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit**

Use `Lazy Eager Loading` because user is already fetched. And for nested relations use `dot syntax`.

Try this

```
Auth::user()->load('sales.items');
```

This will give you nested results to iterate over.

```
User (object)
  |
  |_ User Sales (Collection)
       |
       |_ Items of each sale (Collection)
```

Comment: @JoshBolton Happy to help :-)

Comment: @JoshBolton Awesome!

Comment: Can you help me with the same problem?

Comment: This is a good question, but answer seems to be reckless. It depends when its called, and whenever the loaded relationship is stored in session. If so, switching the sales items will not update for the user.